# Ng-option didn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As the title says, I have a problem with ng-option, here is the code

```
<div class="col col-10">
    <label class="select disabled">
        <select data-ng-option="h.id as h.time for h in dataDiri.home_service_time"
                name="gender"
                ng-model="jamlayanan">
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
```

Here is the http get function in my angularjs code:

```
$scope.lihatDataDiri = function(){
    $http.get('/someurl').success(function(data){
        $scope.dataDiri = data;
    });
};
```

And the result is my select is not functioning, here is the json that I want to get

```
"home_service_time": [{
        "id": "1",
        "time": "08:00 WIB - 10:00 WIB"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "time": "10:00 WIB - 12:00 WIB"
    }, {
        "id": "3",
        "time": "12:00 WIB - 14:00 WIB"
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "time": "14:00 WIB - 16:00 WIB"
    }],
```

So in this case I would like to make my selection in the dropdown is the time and the value that I will pass is on the "id", can anyone help me? I have searched through google but here is the latest work of mine.

Comment: I believe it's a typo error. Use data-ng-options instead of data-ng-option

Comment: Does the `$http.get` function returns anything?

Comment: @BKM I have tried data but didn't worked too

Comment: @choz I think it runs well, I have tried to call it on different field but it returns the data itself

Comment: @YukoPangestu BKM wasn't referring to the `data-` prefix--add make it plural: "option*s*"

Comment: try $scope.dataDiri = data.home_service_time; and in select box change data-ng-option="h.id as h.time for h in dataDiri"

Comment: thanks @MatthewHaugen for the explanation but still doesn't work, the value is still empty

Comment: Try, just for debugging, adding `<pre>{{ dataDiri | json }}</pre>` somewhere in your HTML. That'll tell you where the issue is, then we can go from there. If it's empty, the scope isn't populating what or how you expect. If it's not, your ngOptions is at fault.

Comment: Does "home_service_time" is array in dataDiri or "home_service_time is not a property of dataDiri?

Comment: Thanks @RanjeetSingh but it returns nothing... hmmm, but the json structure is the $scope.dataDiri and then home_service_time and then the nested json like I mentioned above

Comment: waw, what a nice technique @MatthewHaugen I have done that and it returns the content of the json... so my ngOption is for blame

Comment: Are you sure you aren't getting any console errors? I find they're pretty comprehensive, especially for this.

Comment: By the way, I know you said it didn't help, but [ng-option*s*](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#!) is correct. It should be plural. There might be two things wrong, but that's definite.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen good news, my ngOption is work, I think I use the method below me that put the json individually, but my boss said that I have to get it from the api inside the DB, do you have any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working **PLUNKER** with `data-ng-options`:  http://plnkr.co/edit/c3X5bqEcrmKQXXuud4hW?p=preview

Considering that you get the data in the format you have provided with the json.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.9" data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
         <select data-ng-options="h.id as h.time for h in dataDiri.home_service_time" ng-model="jamlayanan ">
               <option value="" disabled>Select</option>
         </select>
      <br>
      <br>
      Data: <input type="text" ng-model="jamlayanan">
    </div>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
      $scope.dataDiri ={ "home_service_time": [{
        "id": "1",
        "time": "08:00 WIB - 10:00 WIB"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "time": "10:00 WIB - 12:00 WIB"
    }, {
        "id": "3",
        "time": "12:00 WIB - 14:00 WIB"
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "time": "14:00 WIB - 16:00 WIB"
    }] };
    });
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using this method now, but my boss need that the value can be get from the api web, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

By Looking at Json you should try this

```
     <select data-ng-options="h.id as h.time for h in dataDiri" name="gender" ng-model="jamlayanan">

        </select>
```